# How to setup a usb Host device

Tags: microcontroller, usb, microchip

How can i setup a usb host device with pic32MX795 with a pendrive as a device .
I have been able to detect the pendrive and enumerate it partially , but cannot create a file on the pendrive .
I am unable to read the no of sector through CBW .

Comment: Can you read from it?

Comment: Which file system format is the pendrive using?

Comment: What is CBW?  Are you using the Microchip Solutions USB and MDD File System libraries?

Comment: I am using the Microchip MLA example: Host - Mass Storage - Simple Demo , in here i try to read the sector size .and get zero .

Comment: I can read the descriptor through endpoint 0, set and address and then setup interface after that  when bulk trasfer starts , no read or write occurs ,

Comment: I have never implemented what you are doing, but this may help (Microchip APP note AN1198): http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01189a.pdf

Comment: I am using pic32mx as host and attaching a pendrive as a device .